# How to put Javascript in Sass?

Tags: html, css, sass, compass-sass

So I'm put this code in my Sass file

```
width: 100%;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
display: -webkit-box;
height: $ font-size *$ line-height *$ lines-to-show;
font-size: $ font-size;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

The code is limit how many lines should show,

---

But it's not working on Sass

I have no idea to fix this one

I search this kind of question, but I can't find it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your variables ($sampleVariable) and remove the space after the `$`. Also you need to define those variables that you used at the top of your file for this to compile.

Your sample code could be like this:

```
// variable definition
$font-size: 1em;
$line-height: 1.3;
$lines-to-show: 3;

// rest of the code
.selector {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: block;
   display: -webkit-box;
   height: $font-size * $line-height * $lines-to-show; // no spaces between $ and variable name
   font-size: $ font-size;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: if this answers your question can you please mark it as an answer?

Comment: sure,   sorry i just forget